# SQLite (.NET), 8 bytes double is converted to 'infinity' rather than double.MaxDouble as inserted?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net, dbdatareader

I am using the SQLite .NET library to save doubles

This is my pseudo-code

```
// create table t1 (value REAL)
// ... connect to db
var sql = $"insert into t1(value) VALUES ({double.MaxValue:G64})"; // insert into t1(value) VALUES (1.7976931348623157E+308)
using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con))
{
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Then I do a select:

```
// SELECT * FROM t1
// .. connect + query
var d = reader.GetDouble(0);
```

But the value of d is `double.PositiveInfinity` rather than `double.MaxValue`, what could be the reason for the difference?

Comment: And if you use parameter instead of converting value to string in insert?

Comment: It's better to use parameters anyway as the current code will break on any system not using the period symbol as decimal separator.

Comment: @Evk, I get a `System.OverflowException`, I think the issue is that `double.MaxValue` in c# is not the same as `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` in c++

Comment: @ckuri, yes, of course, but `double.MaxValue` does not use period/comma, the issue is more about the data not been saved properly on any system.

Comment: @SimonGoodman It does. If I run your code on my German machine I get "1,7976931348623157E+308" - notice the comma instead of the period.

Comment: @ckuri, I see what you are saying, (I was looking at it as a whole number rather than the scientific notation), but in any case, that's not really the issue here as it does not work as a whole/scientific number or not.

Comment: Probably rounding errors.

Comment: @CL., no, the data is saved as `-Inf` or `Inf`, I think it has to do with c++ max double vs c# max double. They are slightly different.